# BeforeClass and AfterClass methods in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to test automation in Selenium Python. I was trying to automate a simple login test and I want to do some things in AfterClass method like in Selenium Java.

I have attached my code here.

test_login.py

```
import unittest
from helper_actions import load_page, type_username, type_password, click_login_button
from helper_assertions import get_welcome_text, read_error_message

class LoginTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        print("Run before each methods")
        load_page()

    def test_valid_username_and_password(self):
        print("test_valid_username_and_password")
        type_username("admin")
        type_password("Ptl@#321")
        click_login_button()
        assert get_welcome_text() == "Welcome Admin"

    def test_valid_username_and_invalid_password(self):
        print("test_valid_username_and_invalid_password")
        type_username("admin")
        type_password("admin")
        click_login_button()
        assert read_error_message() == "Invalid credentials"

    def tearDown(self):
        print("Run after each method")
        super().tearDown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

helper_actions.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(
    ChromeDriverManager().install()))

def load_page():
    driver.get("http://hrm.pragmatictestlabs.com/")

def type_username(username):
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtUsername").send_keys(username)

def type_password(password):
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtPassword").send_keys(password)

def click_login_button():
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnLogin").click()
```

helper_assertions.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(
    ChromeDriverManager().install()))

def get_welcome_text():
    return driver.find_element(By.ID, "welcome").text

def read_error_message():
    return driver.find_element(By.ID, "spanMessage").text
```

How can I add `driver.quit()` at the end of the tests run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anupama Balasooriya you can use setUpClass() and tearDownClass() for your purpose. You can refer this link for details. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html